# Add replace the class of a div upon some conditions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I am trying to replace the class of a `div` with Javascript. I have looked at some posts but it did not seem to help (e.g. [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)). I have a straightforward innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("colored-title").innerHTML = "Add comments";
```

HTML is straightforward as well and it works when there is no condition on the class

```
<div id="colored-title"></div>
```

I tried many options (I listed them all below) but none of them seems to work.

```
if (array[current][5] == 4) { 
    document.getElementById("colored-title").addClass("green-text");
    document.getElementById("colored-title").className= "green-text";
    document.getElementById("colored-title").className+= "green-text";
    document.getElementById("colored-title").setAttribute=("class","green-text");
} else {
    // other format
}
document.getElementById("colored-title").innerHTML = "Add comments";
```

Comment: Some of those should work, some won't, for instance `addClass` is a jQuery method, `setAttribute` is a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: You should try using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) syntax. I believe this is the most straightforward syntax in pure javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the reference. I might be wrong but they do not address the .innerHTML part of the question. I do not want solely to change the class I want to change the class and then be able to emit HTML text through Javascript innerHTML method with the updated class (unless there is another way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery in your project, then setAttribute should look like this:

```
$("#colored-title").attr("class", "green-text");
```

You have to use the jQuery selector, not document.getElementById.

Edit: Worth noting, the .attr method can also set multiple things at once:

```
$("#thing").attr({class:"green-text", title:"green-Object", id:"green-Id"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add classname throught javascript by .classname='classname' 
This should work.check your if condition to see why it is not working

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("colored-title").className= "green-text";
  
}
```

```css
.green-text {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="colored-title">
  hello
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This statement will add the correct class to your div:

```
document.getElementById("colored-title").className= "green-text";
```

But with the following statement you are changing the class from "green-text" to "green-textgreen-text":

```
document.getElementById("colored-title").className+= "green-text";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery in your project, then

```js
$("#elem").addClass("myClass");
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="elem">
 Text
</div>
```